# Passing a php variable into xpath not working

Tags: php, html, xpath, php-5.6, domxpath

I have this below line where I am trying to pass a variable into xpath in PHP.

```
public function getTheIndexVal($index)
{
    $this->click('.//*[@id="js_itemlist"]/li[3]/article/div[$index]/section[1]/ul/li[3]');
}
```

I am calling the above method like,

```
this->getTheIndexVal(3);
```

But the above is throwing an error. Its having $index as it is without substituting the value. This value is being passed as a method argument. I tried the below alternatives. Still no luck.

```
$this->waitForElement('.//*[@id="js_itemlist"]/li['.$index.']/article/div[3]/div/div[1]', 30);

 $this->waitForElement('.//*[@id="js_itemlist"]/li['{$index}']/article/div[3]/div/div[1]', 30);
```

How can I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does $index have any value? if yes, replace $index with direct value and debug it...

Comment: Yes I can print it on the console. I edited the question with what I exactly have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double-quotes for the variable `$index` to be correctly substituted with the corresponding value :

```
public function getTheIndexVal($index)
{
    $this->click(".//*[@id='js_itemlist']/li[3]/article/div[$index]/section[1]/ul/li[3]");
}
```